# Opencart Error - cart- register - icons

Tags: opencart2.x

Basically with Opencart when my site is accessed by my desktop computer it works seamlessly and perfect. When used by a mobile or laptop it generally wont work properly with the same type of error. More specific details:

When trying to register as a new user a dialogue box saying error undefined appears, and as a result the state/region drop down box is empty aswell as many icons do not load. The same error appears when trying to add to cart a product. Is there a way to see a specific error? / more detail of it? It seems sometimes it works great and then a majority of the time on Mobile and Laptop it gets these errors. The desktop computer I used to start the website works perfectly (the website is hosted offshore). Could it be that this might be the result of the hosting I have? I am aware of the broad information but there is not many specifics I can add. Open cart 2.2

Comment: Are you using the same browser on your desktop and on your laptop?

Comment: Try accessing your website with _www.domain.com_ and just _domain.com_. Check your icons. I've found that the opencart icons can act differently depending on some host settings regarding this